# How to show the element wanted in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Here is a part of the tutorial from *Codecademy*.
The instruction is:
**Show the name of each member in the array by "For"**

```
function Personne (nom, age)
{
    this.nom = nom;
    this.age = age;
};

var famille = new Array();
famille[0] = new Personne("alice", 40);
famille[1] = new Personne("bob", 42);
famille[2] = new Personne("michelle", 8);
famille[3] = new Personne("timmy", 6);

for( i=0; i<famille.length; i++)
{
    console.log( famille[i] );
};
```

Which means I need to show:

```
alice
bob
michelle
timmy
```

but with the "For" that I wrote, it shows everything like

```
{ nom: 'alice', age: 40 }
{ nom: 'bob', age: 42 }
{ nom: 'michelle', age: 8 }
{ nom: 'timmy', age: 6 }
```

According  to the tutorial's instruction, I have to creat the array like that
So what is the correct way to get only the name(nom) of each member?
Thanks for those who can help me!

Comment: Sorry about that, as a rookie and learn by myself, I don't think I can easily find the answer in the link that you show me, that's why I prefer to ask on my own, ps, I am learning in french, so I only know very few term in english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to access the object's property and print it,

```
for( i=0; i<famille.length; i++) {
    console.log(famille[i].nom);
};
```

You are printing the object itself.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you so much! I am learning by myself, forgive me for such a rookie question. :)

Comment: @JiangLan Glad to help! :)